# Converting long (numbers) text datatype (with blank values) to date

Tags: postgresql

I have troubles converting HubSpot UNIX timestamp to date. Timestamp is stored as text value.

[image]

Value looks like this:

```
1549324800000
```

My logic was first to convert the number to *bigint* and later converted it to date using:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(properties__vape_station__value)), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

What would be the best way to achieve converting UNIX Timestamp in text type to date in PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Why would you want to convert that to a `text` type. You should convert it to a `timestamp`

Comment: It would be even better I agree, skipping one step. Although when trying to convert text to timestamp via **TO_TIMESTAMP(properties__vape_station__value)**  I get an error:


`No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: I don't mean the intermediate step, I mean the fact that the **final** result shouldn't be a `timestamp` but a `text` value again. Or is this just for display purposes?

Comment: At this point, any would work from which I could extract the actual date.

Comment: `TO_TIMESTAMP(properties__vape_station__value::bigint/1000)` ?

Comment: It returned error:
`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

Comment: Hmm; then it is not "values look like this" like you said. You'll have to sanitize the data.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the values when querying the column [link](http://prntscr.com/mn9kq4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the value in that column to a bigint and then use `to_timestamp`.

But apparently that column also stores empty strings rather than NULL values if no value is present, so you need to take that into account:

```
to_timestamp(nullif(trim(properties__vape_station__value),'')::bigint/1000)
```

This would still fail however if anything else than a number is stored in that column.

Comment: You are correct, there are blank values - only numbers. Will try it asap.

Comment: I've just tried this and it worked. Thank you a lot for the help!